# Wix Installer Advanced UI Welcome Screen flashes by

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I'm building an installer using Wix 3.11, and I've been using the Advanced UI template in order to get the per-machine/per-user installation choice. My issue is that the welcome screen doesn't show. Or more specifically, the welcome screen flashes at the beginning of the installer and goes straight to the License page without any user input. I've noticed that this doesn't happen on some of the other UI templates.

Has anyone else seen this? I even started a fresh project, and it does the same thing.

Comment: I've never seen this.  Please post a log file.

Answer (score 1):

`WixUI_Advanced` doesn't have a welcome screen. The first screen (`AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg`) shows the EULA. There's another modeless dialog (`PrepareDlg`) shown while the `AppSearch` standard action is running; if that happens quickly, it can appear to flash.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up finding out. In my case, since I wanted the welcome screen, I ended up creating my own UI code, based on `WixUI_Advanced` and switching the events around to show the welcome screen first, and then the `AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg`